# Getting rid of Vista's Photo Gallery in favor of Life Photo Gallery

Tags: windows-vista

After installing Windows Live Photo Gallery, I still have the Vista built-in gallery lying around ... is there any way to completely get rid of it (ideally, uninstall) and only use the Live photo gallery for all image viewing?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can turn off or disable the windows photo gallery with some changes in registry. to do so, follow this steps:-

Click on start and type “regedit” in the “Run”.

Click on “Continue” in the next window to open the registry.

Now go to the folder:-

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations.ico\Shel lEx\ContextMenuHandlers\ShellImagePreview.

Highlight the ShellImagePreview key, select File → Export, type a filename, and click Save to back up this Registry key.

Delete the ShellImagePreview key and close the Registry Editor when you're done.

Thats it.. Windows Photo gallery is now disabled

Or

Just right click on the image you want to open and where it says "open with" choose the program of your choice. This will then become the default program for opening that type of image.

Comment: +1 for the open with "Open with" method. Try also "Default programs" through start+search.